# Split Datetime to the clock

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, datetime

**1. Question:** How can I convert this.. 1970-01-01T08:00:00.000+01:00
             to this: 08:00:00 or 08:00

i had use the following function:

```
        var php = '{{ARBEITSZEITBIS}}';   
        var i = php.slice(0,20).split('-');
        var ab = i[2];
```

but than come this output:  01T08:00:00.

I need a good function, not this function, because the datetime is in every document different

```
var d1 = Date.parse('2010-10-18, 10:06 AM');
alert(d1.toString('dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss GMT'));
```

**2. Question**: I do an WKHTMLTOPDF Export with Placeholder, I have checkboxes, when I export this with the Placeholder {{incativ}} come out: true but i need: not given, how can Ireplace this via Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the time part without timezone info from an ISO 8601 timestamp with a couple `split()`:

```
var timestamp = "1970-01-01T08:00:00.000+01:00";
var time = timestamp.split("T")[1].split(".")[0];
// time : "08:00:00"
```

Comment: Thanks :-) Do You know the answer for my secound question?

Comment: Not the slightest idea, but anyway you should post questions in separate posts.